# validate form with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

[image: form]

I have this form.
I needed validate some fileds so I used [this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Options_for_the_validate.28.29_method) with the following code:

```
                $("#filter").validate({
                  rules: {
                    "n-habitaciones": {
                      required: false,
                      number: true
                    },
                    "superficie-min":{
                      required: false,
                      number: true
                    },
                    "superficie-max":{
                      required: false,
                      number: true
                    },
                    "precio-min":{
                      required: false,
                      number: true
                    },
                    "precio-max":{
                      required: false,
                      number: true
                    }

                  }
            });
```

This works fine! but I need setting to empty ("") the input text in "superficie" and "Precio"  on submit if nothing is setting. Values "Desde" and "Hasta" just are label-like.
Here is the form code:

```
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Superficie(m² o Hs)</legend>
            <input type="text" id="superficie-min" name="superficie-min" class="numeric-input" value="Desde" onfocus="if(this.value=='Desde') this.value='';"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Desde';"/>
            <span> - </span>
            <input type="text" id="superficie-max" name="superficie-max" class="numeric-input" value="Hasta" onfocus="if(this.value=='Hasta') this.value='';"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Hasta';"/>
            <br />
            <span class="note">Si busca un campo, ingrese las hectáreas, de otra manera, ingrese m²</span>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Precio</legend>
            <input type="text" name="precio-min" value="Desde" class="numeric-input" onfocus="if(this.value=='Desde') this.value='';"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Desde';"/><span> - </span>
            <input type="text" name="precio-max" value="Hasta" class="numeric-input" onfocus="if(this.value=='Hasta') this.value='';"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Hasta';"/>
        </fieldset>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You just want to set them to an empty string? I didn't understand the constraint. What need to be not set to do this?

Comment: @davidbuzatto, The fields must be filled with numbers but are not required fields. "Desde" and "Hasta" are label-like, so when the input text is on focus "Desde"/"Hasta"  disappear and appear again when the input text is on blur and not filled.
I want to set them to empty when the form is submitted and the fields are not filled.

Comment: May you post yout entire code in jsFiddle? I don't know the library that you are using, but with some complete code I think that is easier to help you.

Comment: Here is the library http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Options_for_the_validate.28.29_method and here is the entire form code: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/J3kY8aUOSD